# Can $\sum_{n=0}^{f(x)} a_n$ (with varying upper limit) have a non-zero derivative?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives

(Based on a recent question deleted by its owner before I could answer. I thought it was interesting enough to post my result.)

Given a sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ and function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$, define $\sigma : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$ \sigma(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{f(x)} a_n $$

(I'll take $\mathbb{N}$ to include $0$ so that we can have $\sigma(x)=0$ where $f(x)=0$, but that doesn't especially matter.)

If $f$ is continuous at any point $x_0$, it follows that $f$ is constant on a neighborhood of $x_0$, and $f'(x_0) = 0$ and $\sigma'(x_0) = 0$.

But if $f$ is not continuous at a point $x_0$, is it possible that $\sigma$ is nevertheless differentiable at $x_0$, with $\sigma'(x_0) \neq 0$?

Comment: The fact $\sigma$ is a sum when $f$ is an arbitrary function doesn't really matter.  $\sigma$ is any function with a countable range.  This simplifies the question a bit.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I think I was just starting to realize that. The telescoping sum in the answer is in fact just a way to use a desired sequence in place of the sum.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For example, take

$$\begin{align*}
a_n &= \begin{cases} -1 & n=1 \\
(-1)^n \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n-1}\right) & n>1 \end{cases} \\
f(x) &= \begin{cases}
2 \lfloor -\frac{1}{x} \rfloor + 1 & x<0 \\
0 & x=0 \\
2 \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor & x>0
\end{cases} \\
x_0 &= 0
\end{align*}$$

$\sigma(x_0) = \sum_{n=1}^0 a_n = 0$ as an empty sum.

Given natural $N \geq 1$,

$$ \sum_{n=1}^N a_n = -1 + \sum_{n=2}^N \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n} - \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n-1}\right) = -1 + \frac{(-1)^N}{N} - \frac{(-1)^1}{1} = \frac{(-1)^N}{N} $$

If $x<0$ and $\lfloor -\frac 1x \rfloor = N$, then

$$ \sigma(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{2N+1} a_n = \frac{(-1)^{2N+1}}{2N+1} = \frac{-1}{2N+1} $$

Since $-\frac 1x -1 < N \leq -\frac 1x$ and $\frac{-1}{2N+1}$ is increasing in $N$,

$$ \frac{-1}{2(-\frac 1x -1) + 1} < \sigma(x) \leq \frac{-1}{2(-\frac 1x) + 1} $$
$$ \frac{x}{2+x} < \sigma(x) \leq \frac{x}{2-x} $$

Similarly, if $0 < x < 1$ and $\lfloor \frac 1x \rfloor = N$, then $N \geq 1$ and

$$ \sigma(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{2N} a_n = \frac{(-1)^{2N}}{2N} = \frac{1}{2N} $$

Since $\frac 1x -1 < N \leq \frac 1x$ and $\frac{1}{2N}$ is decreasing in $N$,

$$ \frac{1}{2(\frac 1x)} \leq \sigma(x) < \frac{1}{2(\frac 1x -1)} $$
$$ \frac{x}{2} \leq \sigma(x) < \frac{x}{2-2x} $$

Therefore

$$ \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{\sigma(x) - \sigma(x_0)}{x - x_0} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sigma(x)}{x} = \frac 12 $$

That is, $\sigma$ is differentiable at $x_0$, and $\sigma'(x_0) = \frac 12 \neq 0$.

A similar construction would give a non-constant $\sigma$ differentiable at any set of isolated points. I doubt $\sigma$ could be differentiable and non-constant on an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ (any proof or disproof?)

Comment: For your final question, if $\sigma$ is non-constant and continuous in a non-empty open interval, its range would be uncountable (by IVP).  Using my characterization from the question comment, this is impossible.